# Firebase index.php

Tags: php, node.js, firebase, google-admin-sdk

I create project on Google Firebase, everything goes perfect uploading my web on Firebase hosting, but `index.php` doesn't work, just `index.html`. So I tried to install PHP through Node.js and Admin SDK, but it still doesn't work... I tried to read the documentation, but I am a beginner in programming and this documentation kills me...

First time I try this: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

After: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

But I cant finish it. Please help or send me any good tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase hosting is for hosting static assets. PHP is executable, so it can't be used in Firebase hosting.

The links you provided are to use Firebase **Database** with your PHP installation in any other host.